# Google Calendar API - Undefined event

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

So, I'm busy with a project. I'm new to node.js but not to javascript. I am wanting to add a calendar event using Node.

This is what I have so far:

```js
 var event = {
   'summary': 'Dinner',
   'location': 'Epic',
   'description': 'Get Coding!',
   'start': {
  'dateTime': '2016-04-30T18:30:00-19:30',
  'timeZone': 'Pacific/Auckland',
   },
   'end': {
  'dateTime': '2016-04-30T19:30:00-20:00',
  'timeZone': 'Pacific/Auckland',
   },
   'recurrence': [
  'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
   ],
   'attendees': [
  {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
  {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
   ],
   'reminders': {
  'useDefault': false,
  'overrides': [
    {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
    {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
  ],
   },
 };
 
 calendar.events.insert({
   auth: auth,
   calendarId: 'primary',
   resource: event,
 }, function(err, event) {
   if (err) {
  console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
  return;
   }
 });
   console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);

 function insertEvents(auth) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  
 }
```

When I run this file, I receive "Event created: undefined" from the console. I have tried multiple ways to fix this with no luck. I took away the ".readonly" from the calendar, I have changed "client_secret" multiple times(new credentials.)

EDIT:

I just found out that I can enter my data into google calendar, but there is something wrong with the times. But that's another problem.

Now, the question is, "why is it undefined?"

Comment: probably remove readonly from scope. I had same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
console.log('Event created: %s', event.data.htmlLink);
```

Instead of

```
console.log('Event created: %s', event.htmlLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log function is looking for an htmlLink in your event, which you have not defined. With the code that google provided, your code will always return undefined.

Simply add this line in the event declaration:

```
'htmlLink' : '/*your HTML Link*/',
```

You could also replace htmlLink with another variable that's already defined, for example 'summary', which might suit your needs more.

Now it returns "Event Created: Dinner"

Answer (score -1):

Where us htmlLink defined? Or is it part of Nodejs.
I would rename var event . At least in the unnamed function it is hidden by the function argument.
Can you single step?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the decently fast reply, I got the code from this link, I also changed the variable names around. Same error. I can pull information from the google calendar, but I cannot add to it. Perhaps somehow, my code thinks that the calendar scope is "read only". https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs#prerequisites

Comment: Your variable (previously event?) does not contain a variable htmlLink. I did not examine the example, but I think you might need to add it. Not sure what it will be used for though.